# Booting from USB not working

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.02 on a 16G USB stick.   First, I booted it "live" from the .iso file.   It took about 4 hours or so to completely install..  I could see the USB light flashing the entire time, and watched the installation log.

When I hit F12 on my Dell Inspiron 3000, I get a boot menu that now has 4 entries under "UEFI Boot":

1. ubuntu (this was not there before)
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. UEFI: CT500MX500SSD1
4. UEFI: General Udisk 5.00

I figured that I was all set, and that 'ubuntu' would be the installation (not Live) on the USB stick, but when I select it, I get a Grub menu that has at least 50 commands, but with none of them could I get Ubuntu to boot.

When I selected #3, I get a Blue screen that says "Boot option restoration", then quickly reboots.

Option #4 *does* boot Ubuntu, but only as the "Live" version with the Install screen, and nothing that I do (obviously) is persistent.

What am I missing here?   I want to have a permanent bootable Ubuntu on my USB that resides entirely on it, but with persistence for apps and data.

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu should take about a half hour to install, but it took about 4 hours or so to completely install Ubuntu on your USB stick. This could be caused by a bad USB stick. Laggy and meager performance happens sometimes when you try to connect a full installation of Ubuntu on a USB stick to your computer's hardware via a USB port. Try using a different USB stick or a different USB port. You might have better luck using a cheap portable SSD, but thumb drive form factor SSDs are prohibitively expensive for most users.

These diagrams will help you to troubleshoot the boot problem further.

[image: flowchart1]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image: flowchart2]

Comment: Just curious what is the source of these great diagrams?

Comment: @N0rbert I used the great and underappreciated draw.io snap package to create these diagrams. The content in the diagrams was provided by C.S.Cameron and myself.

Comment: Great! Will bookmark this answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the diagrams.  I will try and debug this shortly.

Comment: Anything new that you have to report will be a candidate for including in the next revision of the diagrams.